# Mathematica regex equvalent of \l

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

In normal RegEx `\l` will make the character to the right lowercase. However, it seems like the RegEx in Mathematica does not have this functionality.

For example

```
StringCases["Abba", RegularExpression["(.).*?\\l\\1"]]
```

will return the following error message

```
RegularExpression::msg37: "Mathematica does not support \\L, \\l, \\N, \\P, \\p, \\U, \\u, or \\X in RegularExpression[\!\(\"(.).*?\\\\l\\\\1\"\)]."
```

Is there some workaround that I can use? Note that `(?i)` is not sufficient as I need the character to be lowercase *only*.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `[a-z]` if ASCII is sufficient ... otherwise it might not be possible to use regexes and you may need to resort to using string patterns with `_?LowerCaseQ` which I think will be slower.

Comment: @Szabolcs I believe the tricky part is that `\\1` refers to the first byte of the regular expression, which may be also uppercase, but *match* the lowercase letter at end of the regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

```
StringCases["Abba", RegularExpression["(.).*(?=(?i:\\1))[a-z]"]]
```

`(?=(?i:\\1))` is a lookahead which says, "if the next character matches \1 in any case," but then it also has to match the pattern that occupies the place of the next character, which is `[a-z]` i.e. only lowercase letters.

If it fails to match the outer pair of Aa, it will match the inner pair of bb. I couldn't figure out if this was what you wanted or not, it does seem like it judging from your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a regular expression (or PCRE), but it's a `StringExpression` that can be used where `RegularExpression` qualifies:

```
StringCases["Abba", 
 x : LetterCharacter ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ 
   y : LetterCharacter /; ToLowerCase[x] == y]
```

> {"Abba"}

`LetterCharacter`s are used instead of `_` primarily to keep `ToLowerCase` meaningful.